# MySQL select COUNT(*) with if statement

Tags: mysql

I have 1 table that have a lot of records, I want to separate the `COUNT(*)` value (profit/loss), I can do it with 2 MySQL query, but I want to do it with only 1 query, is that possible?

```
$query_string = '
        SELECT 
            MONTH(order_time) AS month,
            CASE WHEN order_profit > 0 THEN COUNT(*) END AS profit,
            CASE WHEN order_profit < 0 THEN COUNT(*) END AS loss,
            COUNT(*) AS total
        FROM
            trade_histories
    ';
$query_string .= '
        WHERE
            order_profit IS NOT NULL
    ';
$query_string .= '
        GROUP BY
            MONTH(order_time) 
    ';
```

This is what I've tried so far, and this is the result

```
stdClass Object ( [month] => 1 [profit] => 447 [loss] => [total] => 447 ) 
stdClass Object ( [month] => 2 [profit] => 1153 [loss] => [total] => 1153 ) 
stdClass Object ( [month] => 3 [profit] => 898 [loss] => [total] => 898 ) 
stdClass Object ( [month] => 4 [profit] => [loss] => 640 [total] => 640 ) 
stdClass Object ( [month] => 12 [profit] => [loss] => 2 [total] => 2 )
```

Comment: I dont understand the core issue... why would you separate the count(*) ?

Comment: @ThomasG because I want to get the `profit` and `loss` count